# Python xbox controller inputs. How to change the message send when a button is pressed

Tags: python, controller, xbox

I am currently making a game and I wanted to add controller support.

Here is my current code:

```
from inputs import get_gamepad
while 1:
    events = get_gamepad()
    for event in events:
        print(event.ev_type, event.code, event.state)
```

I am trying to make it so, for say when I press the A button it sends the message:

```
"a"
```

instead of:

```
Key BTN_SOUTH 1
Sync SYN_REPORT 0
Key BTN_SOUTH 0
Sync SYN_REPORT 0
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `on_press` and `on_release` methods to specify the message that should be sent when a button is pressed or released.

```py
import inputs

# create a controller object
controller = inputs.devices.gamepads[0]

@controller.on_press('A')
def on_press_a(button):
    print("A button pressed")

@controller.on_release('A')
def on_release_a(button):
    print("A button released")
```

You can do the same for any other button on the controller